# Channel Entry sorting refuses to sort in the right order?

Tags: channel-entries, channel, orderby, sort

I have a Channel with a field called `{tour_starting_price}`. It's a text input field, with Type set as `Number`. It only ever stores integers.

I have created a simple template that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="tours" orderby="tour_starting_price" sort="desc" limit="100000"}
        <li>{tour_starting_price}</li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

But the bizarre thing is, the output is returned exactly in this order - which simply isn't ordered descending... Why on earth would this be?

```
4543
4516
3345
2265
2230
2104
2099
2089
1985
1423
1381
1375
995
698
0
24595
15895
15895
13595
10540
10195
9995
9995
9579
9495
6875
6795
6730
6670
6617
6445
6323
6290
5495
5449
5386
5367
5338
5335
5209
5190
5097
5095
4625
4577
4569
4550
4544
4538
4495
4472
3990
3982
3949
3929
3928
3926
3925
3835
3629
3325
3325
3195
3161
3145
3145
3130
3120
3084
3050
2739
2729
2505
2500
2498
2495
2249
2249
2245
2225
2224
2223
2199
2195
2195
2189
2185
2042
2029
2012
1999
1998
1995
1995
1995
1988
1974
1825
1806
1799
1799
1799
1790
1755
1754
1750
1749
1729
1725
1722
1722
1699
1697
1695
1689
1689
1649
1550
1489
1468
1449
1445
1442
1249
1237
1200
1200
1149
1149
1132
1132
1121
1103
1095
918
898
896
850
840
765
765
699
698
688
665
665
320
225
0
0
0
0
-1
-1
```

Comment: Are the first 15 entries returned marked as "Sticky"?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some "sticky" entries, as per [the Docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#sticky) please try adding `sticky="no"` to you channel entries tag and see if that corrects things...

Otherwise please also supply details of if any of these entries have different statuses or future/past posting dates, as the debugging will get a bit more difficult!